# python のitertools.permutationsの使い方を教えて下さい。全部の組み合わせの作り方を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, アルゴリズム, numpy

1年前の問題ですけど、確かめてみたい。
(参考)小学生のみなさんへ、場合の数「2020年度京都大学理系学部数学第5問」にチャレンジしてみて下さい。
https://qiita.com/mrrclb48z/items/a97086d25b3d0bee7125
①[1234]×[1234]×[1234]×[1234]/直積（デカルト積，Cartesian Product）の使い方を教えて下さい。
②全部の組み合わせの作り方を教えて下さい。24×24×24×24＝331766通りです。
　4×3×2×1＝24
よろしくお願いします。
OK
1234
2341
3412
4123

```
# 以下は、めちゃくちゃです。すいません。
import datetime
import numpy as np
import itertools
myList4=[1, 2, 3, 4]
myList=myList4 + myList4 + myList4 + myList4
print(myList)
#
n4=4

print("開始時刻",datetime.datetime.now())
m=0
for v in itertools.permutations(myList):
    result = [v[idx:idx + n4] for idx in range(0, len(v), n4)]
    if (sorted(result[0])!=myList4) :continue
    if (sorted(result[1])!=myList4) :continue
    if (sorted(result[2])!=myList4) :continue
    if (sorted(result[3])!=myList4) :continue
    if (sorted([result[0][0], result[1][0], result[2][0], result[3][0]]) != myList4) :continue
    if (sorted([result[0][1], result[1][1], result[2][1], result[3][1]]) != myList4) :continue
    if (sorted([result[0][2], result[1][2], result[2][2], result[3][2]]) != myList4) :continue
    if (sorted([result[0][3], result[1][3], result[2][3], result[3][3]]) != myList4) :continue
    m = m + 1
    # print('m ###',m,"###",result)
print('終了m ###',m)
print("終了時刻",datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「2020年度京都大学理系学部数学第5問」にチャレンジしてみて下さい。

```
import itertools
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
lst=[1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
for v0 in itertools.permutations(lst):
    for v1 in itertools.permutations(lst):
        if any(v0[n] == v1[n] for n in range(len(lst))):
            continue
        for v2 in itertools.permutations(lst):
            if any(v0[n] == v2[n] or v1[n] == v2[n] for n in range(len(lst))):
                continue
            for v3 in itertools.permutations(lst):
                if any(v0[n] == v3[n] or v1[n] == v3[n] or v2[n] == v3[n] for n in range(len(lst))):
                    continue
                result.append([v0]+[v1]+[v2]+[v3])

print(*result, sep='\n')
print(len(result))  # 576
end = time.perf_counter()
print("所要時間", (end - start)*1000, "ms")  # 100 -> 1000 に 修正
```

> ②全部の組み合わせの作り方を教えて下さい。24×24×24×24＝331766通りです。

24×24×24×24 は 331776通りですね。

```
import itertools

lst=[1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
for v0 in itertools.permutations(lst):
    for v1 in itertools.permutations(lst):
        for v2 in itertools.permutations(lst):
            for v3 in itertools.permutations(lst):
                result.append([v0]+[v1]+[v2]+[v3])

print(len(result))  # 331776
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4]
m=0
for v0 in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    for v1 in itertools.permutations(my_list):
        for v2 in itertools.permutations(my_list):
            for v3 in itertools.permutations(my_list):
                my_result=[v0]+[v1]+[v2]+[v3]
                if (sorted([my_result[0][0], my_result[1][0], my_result[2][0], my_result[3][0]]) != my_list): continue
                if (sorted([my_result[0][1], my_result[1][1], my_result[2][1], my_result[3][1]]) != my_list): continue
                if (sorted([my_result[0][2], my_result[1][2], my_result[2][2], my_result[3][2]]) != my_list): continue
                if (sorted([my_result[0][3], my_result[1][3], my_result[2][3], my_result[3][3]]) != my_list): continue
                m = m + 1
print(m)  # 576
```