# sympyの代入方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

私の代入のどこが、おかしいですか？
myV0に整数しか入らないと思っていました。

(参考)
[python のitertools.permutationsの使い方を教えて下さい。全部の組み合わせの作り方を教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73763/python-%e3%81%aeitertools-permutations%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e6%96%b9%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84-%e5%85%a8%e9%83%a8%e3%81%ae%e7%b5%84%e3%81%bf%e5%90%88%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9b%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8a%e6%96%b9%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84/73774#73774)

```
from sympy import *
var('V0 V1 myV0 myV1')
my_list=list(range(2))
print(my_list)
for v0 in my_list:
    for v1 in my_list:
        myV0=V0
        myV1=V1
        print(v0,v1,myV0,myV1)
# [0, 1]
# 0 0 V0 V1
# 0 1 V0 V1
# 1 0 V0 V1
# 1 1 V0 V1
```

Comment: 「myV0に整数しか入らないと思っていました。」　質問の意味がよく分かりません。どういった出力を想定されていたのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonは大文字と小文字を区別します。

```py
        myV0=V0
        myV1=V1
```

の右辺を

```
        myV0=v0
        myV1=v1
```

のようにしてください。

追記: [`sympy.var()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#var)はシンボルを返すだけでなく、グローバルスコープに変数を定義します。つまり、

```py
var('V0 V1 myV0 myV1')
```

によって、`V0`、`V1`、`myV0`、`myV1`が定義されてしまっているので、

```py
        myV0=V0
        myV1=V1
```

と誤って書いてしまっても`V0`や`V1`は未定義エラーを起こしません。

グローバルスコープに変数を定義したくないのであれば[`sympy.var()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#var)ではなく[`sympy.symbols()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#symbols)を使うべきです。

Answer (score 0):

pycharmでpylintしてみました。'V0','V1'(undefined-variable)でした。

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\pylint.exe C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py
************* Module main
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py:8:13: E0602: Undefined variable 'V0' (undefined-variable)
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py:9:13: E0602: Undefined variable 'V1' (undefined-variable)
他
```

直しました。

```
from sympy import *
my_list=list(range(2))
print(my_list)

for v0 in my_list:
    for v1 in my_list:
        myV0=v0
        myV1=v1
        print(v0,v1,myV0,myV1)
# [0, 1]
# 0 0 0 0
# 0 1 0 1
# 1 0 1 0
# 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: この場合、Pylintは[`sympy.var()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.var)がグローバルスコープに変数を生成することを認識できていません。実際、オリジナルの例題では、`V0`, `V1`が`var(...)`を実行することによって定義されています。